# Passing variable to function and back

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, scope

I'm trying to figure out why this isn't working. I thought I understood scope...

```
var admin_data = false;
function getPlayerAdmin(){
    var formData = {
        'player_id' : $('#post-v').attr('data-val')
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/popins/player/controls',
        data : formData,
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(admin_data) {
            if(admin_data.controls.is_admin == true){
                admin_data = true;
            }else{
                admin_data = false;
            }
        }
    });
}
alert(admin_data);
```

So basically admin_data is being set to true, however it doesn't change it when I alert it after. How do I pass this back down?

Thanks!

So far I have this now:

```
var admin_data = false;

adminData(function(admin_data) {
    if(admin_data_vals.controls.is_admin == true){
        admin_data = true;
    }else{
        admin_data = false;
    }
});

function getPlayerAdmin(adminData){
    var formData = {
        'player_id' : $('#post-v').attr('data-val')
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/popins/player/controls',
        data : formData,
        dataType : 'json',
        success: adminData
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }
    });
}
alert(admin_data);
```

3rd attempt:

```
var admin_data = false;
function getPlayerAdmin(admin_data){
    var formData = {
        'player_id' : $('#post-v').attr('data-val')
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/popins/player/controls',
        data : formData,
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(admin_data_vals, admin_data) {
            if(admin_data_vals.controls.is_admin == true){
                admin_data = true;
            }else{
                admin_data = false;
            }
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }
    });
}
getPlayerAdmin();
alert(admin_data);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Not understanding that post, too much going on.

Comment: The gist is that you need to call a function from inside the success handler which uses the data, or use Promises. I highly recommend reading the first few answers though. You will learn a lot about how asynchronous code works.

Comment: Because the request has not been completed.. Yet you are already displaying the result.. When doing an ajax call. There is a delay before the data received. If you check the flow of your code. You're expecting that the request is already complete before it runs your alert call

Comment: Now that makes sense, thanks guys. I know about async, I just figured it applied to the function itself, I didn't know it waited and jumped to said next functions. Damn.

Comment: Still having troubles figuring out a solution though.

Comment: Look under "Restructure code" in the first answer.

Comment: I've been looking it at for like 30 minutes. I don't understand it because there is no callback variable.

Comment: The guy doesn't explain it in order properly.

Comment: I've updated my question which is what I believe to be what he is explaining...

Comment: What is the 'result' variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can do many things here to resolve this with things like promises, deferred objects, etc., but you could simply just do your logic in the success/error callbacks if there isn't much complexity to what you need to do with the response.

```
success: function(adminData) { // Should probably change the parameter name
                               // to not be the same as the variable you are setting
  if (adminData.controls.is_admin == true) {
    admin_data = true;
    alert(admin_data);
  } else {
    admin_data = false;
    alert(admin_data);
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't return the variable to be used in another function.

Comment: Sure it does, replace alert with your function

Comment: You're missing the point. I'm trying to get admin_data variable in another function. I can't load that function in the success.

Comment: Why can't you? How does your function look like?